# Python3 : How to escape special characters for cx_oracle continuous stream of insert statement (ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated)

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I am using python code which reads the CSV file and for every row it inserts in Oracle Database.

Is there anyway to overcome "ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated" error for all use cases.

Special Characters which I want to escape are  Single Quote ('), Double Quotes ("), Comma (,) and  Others if that can lead to error.

My logic is actually below :

```
    with open(files, newline='',  encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        rowreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
        next(rowreader)
        for row in rowreader:
            values = parseCSV.input(row)
            query = "INSERT INTO MYTABLE(col1,col2) values('{val1}','{val2}')".format(**values)
            cursor.execute(query)
```

Above doesn't works for if string to be inserted - 'my's name'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes -- use parameters/binds.

Via the [`cx_oracle` manual on using binds](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html):

```
# assuming `values` is a dict with `val1` and `val2`:
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO MYTABLE (col1, col2) values(:val1, :val2)", values)
```

Also note how the manual page says "never do this!!!" for how you interpolate data into your statement - your code would currently vulnerable be to SQL injection attacks too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but my values is dictionary. how to replace the dictionary values as val1, val2

Comment: According to the manual, a dictionary should work just fine. https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-by-name-or-position

Comment: If you're inserting multiple records, be sure to check out the cx_Oracle documentation [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's an example in the [documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html) that will be a lot faster than calling `execute()` for each row:

```
import cx_Oracle
import csv

. . .

# Predefine the memory areas to match the table definition
cursor.setinputsizes(None, 25)

# Adjust the batch size to meet your memory and performance requirements
batch_size = 10000

with open('testsp.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    sql = "insert into test (id,name) values (:1, :2)"
    data = []
    for line in csv_reader:
        data.append((line[0], line[1]))
        if len(data) % batch_size == 0:
            cursor.executemany(sql, data)
            data = []
    if data:
        cursor.executemany(sql, data)
    con.commit()
```